# Use Audio port as input and output

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I have a Macbook Pro 2011, running OS X Yosemite. I am trying to use my headphones, which contain a mic and speakers (as most headphones do). However, I can only use the audio jack as input or output. I have tried to change it, but whenever I go to the sound menu to select it, it only gives me Input or Output.

See:

[image: a busy cat]

Is there really a reason why this audio port cannot be used as both at the same time? Did I mess something up? Is there a third party method to use it as both at the same time?

Comment: It is all in the plug. Are those Apple headset ? do they have 3 black rings or 2 on the plug.

Comment: 3 black rings. However, I have used Apple earbuds and they do not work either.

Comment: 3 is good, that should work, what does your syst pref sound shows when you plug it in.

Comment: Edited to include pictures.

Comment: It looks like the 2011 13" MBP has a port that only supports one or the other, many forum threads suggest getting usb headphones or microphone.